# Nagios Error : requested URL /nagios not found

Tags: nagios, apache2

I installed Nagios Core from here on Ubuntu 16.04 https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/Installing_Nagios_Core_From_Source.pdf 
And I cannot access /nagios on the server. Apache2 and Nagios are running as per systemctl status. I do see `stderr line 01: /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/sendmail: not found` and `stderr line 02: /usr/bin/printf: write error: Broken pipe` in the nagios status. Not sure if thats causing the issue.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You fix the configuration issues. If you want any further help, you need to actually include the actual configuration.

Comment: I put the fix below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy /etc/apache2/nagios.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-available/nagios.conf and also create a symlink to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ directory.

`sudo cp /etc/apache2/nagios.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/nagios.conf`

`sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/nagios.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Solution is here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04